# Gradle: Call Task from Imported Plugin in My Own Tasks

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I'm used to Maven but currently I'm using Gradle and I'm not really sure how to call tasks defined by other plugins. (Edit: I'm able to call these tasks in the CLI, but I'd like to also invoke them in my own, custom-defined tasks.)

But I'm importing [this plugin](https://github.com/sherter/google-java-format-gradle-plugin) to format (and enforce format) of my Java project; the tasks I'm most interested in calling are `goJF` and `verGJF`.

I've tried a few ways to either call included tasks and I've done even more Googling. I can share some of the (probably embarrassing) ways I've tried to call other tasks if it's helpful, but figured that might be unnecessary information at this point.

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    // https://github.com/sherter/google-java-format-gradle-plugin
    id 'com.github.sherter.google-java-format' version '0.9'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:30.0-jre")
    testImplementation(platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.0'))
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.0')
}

// Alias for goJF:
task fmt  {
    goJF
}

// Alias for verGJF:
task vfmt {
    verGJF
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "call from the command-line" or "call from your own Gradle tasks" ? What is the goal for the "alias" tasks in your example?

Comment: I mean to call from my own Gradle task. In this case, the point of aliasing is just to simplify the commands since I'm not a huge fan of the task names given, so it'd be nice if instead of typing `gradle goJF` in my CLI, I can just type `gradle fmt` or instead of `gradle verGJF`, I can type `gradle vfmt`.

It may be arbitrary to some, but it's something that I would prefer and, in this case, calling plugin tasks from my own tasks seems like something that should be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_64652901).

From the [documentation](https://github.com/sherter/google-java-format-gradle-plugin), we note that there are examples of configuring the plugin tasks. So aliasing is a simplification of that approach. Consider:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    // https://github.com/sherter/google-java-format-gradle-plugin
    id 'com.github.sherter.google-java-format' version '0.9'
}

import com.github.sherter.googlejavaformatgradleplugin.GoogleJavaFormat
import com.github.sherter.googlejavaformatgradleplugin.VerifyGoogleJavaFormat

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:30.0-jre")
    testImplementation(platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.0'))
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.0')
}

task fmt(type: GoogleJavaFormat) {
}

task vfmt(type: VerifyGoogleJavaFormat) {
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Here `fmt` is a new task of type `GoogleJavaFormat`; `vfmt` is of type `VerifyGoogleJavaFormat`. These instances can specify their own configuration (and do other things with `doFirst`, `doLast`, etc). But as-is, they act as aliases.

Answer (score 0):

A few distinctions to begin with. The built in tasks defined by the plugin are called `googleJavaFormat` and `verifyGoogleJavaFormat`.

These tasks are immediately available to you once you have included the plugin which it seems you have done correctly from what I can see.

On the gradle command line, gradle implements a abbreviation functionality where you can call things with shorthand like:

```
~> gradle gooJF
```

which is shorthand for:

```
~> gradle googleJavaFormat
```

but this only works on the command line and only as long as your shorthand uniquely identifies a task name.

So when you work with tasks in the `build.gradle` file you will need to use the full name.

In gradle you create a new task via:

```
task SomeTaskName(type: SomeClassImplementingTheTask) {
  // some configuration of the task
}
```

In your case you would want to do one of two things:

1. configure the two existing tasks added by the plugin so that they do what you want *or* if the tasks already do what they should, you might not need to configure them and can just run them as is.
2. create your own tasks with your own names but using the implementing classes (i.e. replacing `SomeClassNameImplementingTheTask` above with `GoogleJavaFormat` or `VerifyGoogleJavaFormat`) defined by the plugin.

The simplest of the two is to configure the already existing tasks. This can be done as follows:

```
googleJavaFormat {
  source = sourceSets*.allJava
  source 'src/special_dir'
  include '**/*.java'
  exclude '**/*Template.java'
  exclude 'src/test/template_*'
}
```

The `googleJavaFormat` used here is actually a "plugin extension" which is exposed by the plugin. Plugin extensions are explicitly there for you to be able to alter the behavior of the plugin through configuration.

Note that the configurations options I defined are just examples, there are probably more things you can set here. The above would modify the two existing tasks with your custom settings and you could then call them from the command line using:

```
~> gradle googleJavaFormat
```

and

```
~> gradle verifyGoogleJavaFormat
```

Again, perhaps you don't even need to configure things and in that case you should just be able to call the tasks as in the above example.